# Python/Google app engine data storage performance

Tags: python, performance, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In a python/google app engine app, I've got a choice between storing some static data (couple KB in size) in a local json/xml file or putting it into the datastore and querying it from there.  The data is created by me, so there's no issues with badly formed data.  In specific terms such as saving quota, less resource usage and app speed, which is the better method for this case?

I'd guess using simplyjson to read from a json file would be better since this method doesn't require a datastore query, whilst still being reasonably quick.

Taking this further, the app doesn't require a large data store (currently ~400KB), so would it be worthwhile moving all the data to a json file to get around the quota restrictions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is small, static and infrequently changed, you'll get the best performance by just writing your data as a `dict` in it's own module and just `import` it where you need it. This would take advantage of the fact that Python will cache your modules on import.

Comment: +1; avoiding the overhead of deserializing JSON or parsing XML is a Good Idea, although there might be cases where it's much easier to maintain the data in one of those formats.

Answer (score 1):

For superior app performance, as Chris and others pointed out, python dict is the best.

But if you are ok with the minimal performance hit caused by datastore queries, I think that is the way to go purely from a design and maintenance perspective.  Simplicity takes precedence over performance if you are not approaching the quota limits.

I assume yours is a simple app as of today. But it can gradually grow in complexity.  As you add more features, having a hard-coded data somewhere will come in the way of design flexibility even in the short term.  And you might end up rewriting those areas in future.

Comment: That's a good point. The balance between human time/ease vs machine time/ease is a difficult one to get right. But, in the case of google app engine, which enforces performance and speed through a "reward and punishment" scheme by design, it seems better to lean a little towards performance.  But I get what you're saying, rapid dev to begin with and worry about performance tuning and efficiency when an app becomes worthy of the time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

It is faster to keep your data in a static file instead of the datastore. As you said, this saves on datastore quota, and also saves time in round-trips to the datastore.

However, any **data you store in static files is static and cannot be changed by your application** (see the ["Sandbox" section here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html)). You would need to re-deploy the file each time you wanted to make changes (i.e. none of the changes could be made through a web interface). If this is acceptable, then use this method, since it's simple and fast.